# Xcode7 beta のシュミレーターでは動画が動くが、実機テストでは再生されません。。

Tags: xcode

MACBOOKAIR OS10.11.3n Xcode-betaを使用しています。
タイトルに書いた通り実機テストで動画が再生できません。。
mov.mp4やquicktimeやCNVERTERで様々なものを試しましたがダメでした。

プログラムは以下になります。

```
import Foundation
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController0: UIViewController {


    var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    var playerView = AVPlayer()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "ここに動画fileを挟み込んでいます")
        playerView = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL)

        playerViewController.player = playerView

        self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true){}

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func playbuttontapped(sender: UIButton) {
        //Trigger the video to play
    }
}
```

かれこれ１週間はまってます。。
どうか宜しくお願い致します！！

Answer (score 0):

"ここに動画fileを挟み込んでいます"とありますが、動画のパスを直接指定されているのでしょうか？もしそうでしたら、シミュレータではMac上のファイルは参照できますが、実機からは参照する事ができません。
動画ファイルをアプリにバンドルして下記のようにNSBundleでパスを取得して利用する

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("movie", ofType: "mp4") {
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    playerView = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL)
    playerViewController.player = playerView
    self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

もしくは、実機からアクセスできるところに動画ファイルを置いて、そのURLのNSURLを作成して再生すると良いと思います。

もしこのようにされている場合はご容赦を。

---

追記

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    var playerView = AVPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("name", ofType: "mp4") {
            let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            playerView = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL)
            playerViewController.player = playerView
            self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) {}
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    }
}
```

Comment: r.izumita様
ご回答ありがとうございます。まさか当日にご連絡いただけていたとは知らず、今気がつきました。。
実は半ば諦めかけていたので、これが僕の最後のトライになると思います。
まず私は本当に初心者で、御呈示いただいたプログラムをどう扱えばいいのかもわかりません。。ご迷惑をお掛けして申し訳ございません。
まず私がしたことは既存のプログラムの

let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "ここに動画fileを挟み込んでいます")
    playerView = AVPlayer(URL: fileURL)

    playerViewController.player = playerView

    self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true){


    }
}

この部分を　r.izumita様に御呈示いただいたプログラムに変換しました。
で、ここからどうすれば良いかわからないのです。。

ifとletの間に’；’この記号を入れろだの何だの赤の！が表示されてしまいます、、

こんな初歩的な質問に答えていただけますでしょうか？？

何卒宜しくお願い致します。
今回はメールに通知が来る様に設定いたしましたので、すぐお返事ができると思います。

Comment: 動画ファイルはMac内にあるのでしょうか。それともネット上にありURLでアクセスできるのでしょうか。まずそれを教えてください。

Comment: すみません！MAC内にありまして、mp４になります

情報は

大きさ　６４０　４８０
コーデック　AAC H 264
カラープロファイル　HD１−１−１−
再生時間３０：１５
オーディオチャンネル　２

お忙しい中誠にありがとうございます！

Comment: その動画ファイルはXcodeのプロジェクトに入っていてアプリにバンドルされるようになっていますか？なっていなければ、プロジェクトに追加してください。（大きいファイルのようなので、実際のリリースではアプリにバンドルするのはおすすめしませんが。）
それから
NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("movie", ofType: "mp4")
のmovieとmp4をバンドルした動画ファイルの名前と拡張子に変えてください。
コードエラーですが、質問に追記の形でコードもしくはそのスクリーンショットを掲載してください。
よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます！！
そしてよろしくお願いします。
まず、動画ファイルはdrug&dropでプロジェクトに追加しております。
次に名前と拡張子は以下になります。
ScreenRecord 2016-15minite ver. 16-27-14.mp4

追記でスクリーンショットを掲載させていただきます。http://firestorage.jp/download/56822cb78542cb4d6502329bde207059671380d9

Comment: if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ScreenRecord2016-16minite ver. 16-27-14(1)", ofType: "mp4") {
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
のように、pathForResourceの第1引数はディレクトリと拡張子を除いたファイル名にしてください。NSURLのイニシャライズの引数は、if letで取得した'path'を指定します。
@IBActionbuttontapped(sender: UIButton)の箇所の問題は@IBAction func buttontapped(sender: UIButton)とします。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
早速訂正してみましたが、
最後に一つだけエラーが出ております。。
以下スクリーンでございます。http://firestorage.jp/download/42b0ba9f329690c16ecbd89f63377510d8a5eb81

Comment: {が足りてないです。エラーの箇所を
@IBAction func buttontapped(sender: UIButton) {
とします。

Comment: 再度エラーが出てしまいました。。
誠に申し訳ないです。
まず以下のようになりhttp://firestorage.jp/download/51bc3ce3f889930bf0d1dbe651a1aea702b1327f
次に赤丸をタップすると以下になりましたhttp://firestorage.jp/download/1b3c19c9ac2fec5ab6e0b98584c3df12211aa56a

Comment: すみません、リンクが開けないです。

Comment: いかがでしょうか？
ひとつ目　　http://firestorage.jp/download/cb515ed3038bea760116389312e6286718b4efed

Comment: 二つめ　　　http://firestorage.jp/download/72a7bf4b5edb4b08c9038c9ffc43619da852a843

Comment: そのメソッドのエラーはちょっとわからないので、メソッドを削除して実行するか、削除して再度作成するかしてみてください。

Comment: 一つ目のエラーは消えました！！
最後にこれだけ残りました、、　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　http://firestorage.jp/download/fefb57acccfd54214ffa37516011e70656d92f4f

Comment: やはり良く分からないので、クラスを完全に一から書いてみるとどこが悪いのか分かるかもしれません。
またNSURLを作成するところはNSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)とします。
それからviewDidAppearの先頭にsuper.viewDidAppear(animated)を挿入してください。

Comment: ご指摘の通りやってみましたが、あってますでしょうか。。？
現状このような感じです。　　　　http://firestorage.jp/download/b657aebbf850c2a749afec79338a2caa87cf4aa3
原因がわからなければもう一度一からやってみようと思います。
何度もありがとうございます！！

Comment: その警告箇所は
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
にします。

Comment: 現状こちらになります。　　　　　
　　http://firestorage.jp/download/b38959775fab0f2db335bf221e2604175a276e64

Comment: 回答にコードを追記しました。
NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("name", ofType: "mp4")
のnameの部分をお持ちのファイル名に変更して利用してみてください。

Comment: このようになりました。
宜しくお願い致します。

http://firestorage.jp/download/72e6d82dad6c7cfc3e063f544527b5e293b0e126

Comment: 追記したコードではないようです。コピペしてnameだけ修正してみてください。

Comment: すみません！
コピペでnameだけ修正しました。　　　　　http://firestorage.jp/download/d9423892c1d7f3e9695aea321a656d10b598a702

Comment: いや、全てのコードをコピペしてください{とかoverrideとか抜けがあります。

Comment: すみません。。
状況がつかめなくなってきました、、

すべてのコードをコピペするとはどういう意味でしょうか。。？

Comment: 上のほうの、回答の本文に「追記」と記してコードを貼り付けてあります。そのコードをコピペしてみてください。

Comment: 回答にコードを追記しました。 NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("name", ofType: "mp4") のnameの部分をお持ちのファイル名に変更して利用してみてください。 – r.izumita 1 時間前

このことでしょうか？？

Comment: あ、いや、 https://www.dropbox.com/s/g094cp9ikg5qqdk/answer.png?dl=0 これのことです。

Comment: 勘違いすみません。。
今すべてコピペしてnameだけ入れ替えて、早速実機テストを行ったところ、画面が真っ白で何も表示されません。。
xcode内は現状こうなっています。　　　　http://firestorage.jp/download/8d3d226bceaa4d14eaf0a63245fff02e57c449d3

Comment: コメント欄は長期にわたるやり取りには向きません。ここまでのやり取りを[チャットに移動しました](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36690/discussion-on-answer-by-r-izumita-xcode7-beta-)ので、続きはそちらでお願いします。

Comment: チャットでの返信の仕方がわからなかったので、こちらでコメントさせてください。break pointに関して全く無知なのでご教授いただけませんでしょうか？すみません。。

Comment: breakpointが分からないレベルですと、一度Xcodeの使い方をネットや書籍で学ばれた方が良いと思います。ここだけのサポートで完了するように思われませんので。後少しなので頑張ってください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！また後日ご連絡いたします。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: すみません。チャットに戻れなくなってしまい、先ほどのr.izumitaさんのコメントが見れなくなってしまいました。。
こちらにもう一度コメントしていただけると助かります。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: @1010 チャットルームはここですね： http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36690/ 各メッセージの右下にカーソルを乗せると3つのアイコンが表示され、右端に出る矢印みたいなアイコンをクリックすると返信できます。

Comment: r.izumitaさん
お待たせいたしました。
break point を作りましたがダメでした。。
ご覧いただけますでしょうか？
宜しくお願い致します。

http://firestorage.jp/download/1e58765696c26f3ecfb027352713bb55f8db39e0

Comment: 返信をチャットルームに書きます。

Comment: すみません
なぜかチャットで返信できません。。

一行ずつやりましたがあってますでしょうか？

http://firestorage.jp/download/d7fb01778af95db89aaaf0ab8162d6e44ad1aec3

Comment: 改行を入れているだけになってます。Xcodeのデバッガの使い方を検索してみてください。

Comment: こういうことでしょうか。。？

http://firestorage.jp/download/6fd65a6af4c3494b43c4cee55f164a7eaca1acd2

Comment: これで30行目に到達するかどうかなのですが、引き続き実行してみてください。

Comment: いかがでしょうか？　　　http://firestorage.jp/download/43d578e1f867a5300abac56e2fb804fc5d04462b

Comment: if文まで到達してないです。デバッガでのステップ実行について調べてください。

Comment: r.izumita様
この度はたくさんのご指導ありがとうございました。
一度基礎的な事を勉強してからまたご連絡いたします。
本当にありがとうございました！